# How do I set the color of a toggle button in wxpython?

Tags: button, colors, wxpython, togglebutton

I have a collection of button that I've created and need to change the color of the button when it's pressed.  Currently it set the default colors (grey = inactive; light blue = active):

[image]

but I want to change the color of active to red.

Here's my button class:

```
class ButtonClass(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, name, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.name = name
        self.taskid = id

        self.button = wx.ToggleButton(self, 1, size=(50, 50))
        self.button.SetLabel('Start')

        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.button)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, self.toggledbutton, self.button)

    # Where the buttons change state
    def toggledbutton(self, event):

        # Active State
        if self.button.GetValue() == True:

            self.button.SetLabel('Stop')

        # Inactive State
        if self.button.GetValue() == False:

            self.button.SetLabel('Start')
```

I've tried using `self.button.SetColour` , `self.button.SetBackgroundColour` , `self.button.SetForegroundColour` all of which were not successful.  Is there a way to accomplish this within wxpython?

Comment: I am fairly confident this is OS / Theme specific and that you don't get control over it, but I am not 100% certain of that.

Comment: @g.d.d.c - I was scared of that, but wasn't sure.

Comment: Let me run a few tests, I have a couple of ToggleButtons in a part of one of my projects.  I'll update here in a few minutes with what I find.

Comment: I'm likewise unable to control the highlighting color of these controls.  SetOwnBackgroundColor seems to set the color for the region behind the button in the containing sizer, but I can't affect the actual button in any of the standard approaches.  I'm leaning toward not possible, but I'm starring this in case anyone else has a way.

Comment: This statement from Robin Dunn indicates that it's a limitation of wxWidgets http://groups.google.com/group/wxpython-users/msg/ac60f3a1ef05197b .

Comment: You can always create a custom button and then you can set whatever colors you like.

Comment: @Bogdan: I just don't like the look of the custom button, unless you mean a bitmap button, which I don't want to hassle with ATM.

Comment: You could always look at what the AGW stuff might provide... I used their FlatNotebook once because it gave support to somethings I was trying to do there.  They have something called the [Aqua Button](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/AGW_Docs/aquabutton.AquaButton.html#aquabutton-aquabutton) that may work for you...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be platform dependant. This worked for me in Ubuntu, but not in Windows.

```
self.ToggleButtonObj = wx.ToggleButton(self, -1, 'ButtonLabel')
self.ToggleButtonObj.Bind(wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, self.OnToggleClick)

def OnToggleClick(self,event):
    if self.ToggleButtonObj.GetValue():
         self.ToggleButtonObj.SetBackgroundColour('#color1')
    else:
         self.ToggleButtonObj.SetBackgroundColour('#color2')
```

---

Workaround:

```
    self.Button = wx.Button(self, -1, 'ButtonLabel')
    self.Button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnToggleClick)
    self.ButtonValue = False

    def OnToggleClick(self,event):
        if not self.ButtonValue():
             self.Button.SetBackgroundColour('#color1')
             self.ButtonValue = True
        else:
             self.Button.SetBackgroundColour('#color2')
             self.ButtonValue = False
```

Answer (score 0):

SetBackgroundColour() worked for me using colour in RGB mode (like (255,255,255)) in Windows 7 with python 2.7.3.